# Trying to train a VGG16 CNN with Tensorflow with no success

Tags: python, tensorflow, vgg-net

I'm try to train a VGG16 empty model to classify 7 types of creatures:

[image]

The data in each directory is lots of variations of the same creature (diffrent colors, diffrent angle views from 0 to 10, diffrent face), each training class have ~6500 variations, each testing class have ~2500 variations)
[image]

I use this code to initialize and empty VGG16 model with 7 cassificatioon on the last layer softmax and train the model:

```
VGGModel = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = Sequential([
    VGGModel,
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(7, activation='softmax'),
])

trdata = ImageDataGenerator()
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(directory="SaveImages/traindata",target_size=(224,224))

tsdata = ImageDataGenerator()
testdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(directory="SaveImages/testdata",target_size=(224,224))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

hist = model.fit_generator(steps_per_epoch=40,generator=traindata, validation_data= testdata, validation_steps=10,epochs=20)
```

This is the result:
[image]

The accuracy is about 14% (even when trying larger step size) which is the same as chance value (100% divided by 7 classes), any ideas how to train the model to clasify these creatures?

Comment: I see you don't normalize your image data. That can make the network have a hard time to converge. Try to scale the data between 0 and 1 by providing the argument `rescale=1/255.` to the `ImageDataGenerator`

Comment: @Lescurel, I added the rescale parameter, but still the results are the same

Comment: Check your data pipeline, that you do get the expected data/label pairs. It's usually where the problem is. You can also try to reduce/increase your learning rate. I don't see any obvious mistake in your code, so I would guess there's a problem in the data side of things.

Comment: Hi @Lior Bruder, Could you please share the standalone code along with the data preprocessing part to replicate and understand the issue.